# Give an example of a metric space $(X,d)$ where $B_{r}(x) = B_{r}[x]$ for every $x\in X$ and every $r\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, examples-counterexamples

**Exercise**

Give an example of a metric space $(X,d)$ where $B_{r}(x) = B_{r}[x]$ for every $x\in X$ and every $r\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$. Given another example where it does not occur.

**My attempts**

I have thought about the set of rationals $\mathbb{Q}$, but it fails to be the case, since we can have rational endpoints in an interval.

I have also tried to think about the discrete metric space, but it does not solve the problem neither.

Could anyone help me with this?

This is not homework. I am just studying the subject and I would like to understand it better.

Comment: Can you recall what's $B_{r}(x)$ and $B_{r}[x]$?

Comment: It is the open and closed balls (in that order) centered at $x$ with radius $r > 0$.

Comment: Try to think about finite set first. Sets with one, or two elements would give you the answer.

Comment: @ArcticChar Thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $x \neq y$ take $B_{d(x,y)}(x)$ If your space exists then $y \in B_{d(x,y)}(x)$ . Therefore $ d(x,y)< d(x,y)$ which is absurd.
So the space must have only one point.